# How to open standard phone number view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My application will receive some phone numbers, and I want to show these phone numbers to user by stardard iOS phone number view controller, like image attached.

[image: iPhone screenshot]

I looking for way, how to open this view controller in my code, and pass phone number to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) covers all the ways you can interact with the user's Address Book. It sounds like you want to add phone numbers to new or existing contacts therefore the [User Interaction: Prompting for and Displaying Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1) will probably be the best place to start.